# Core data: Why removing the sqlite file did not clear all the previous data insert immediately?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, core-data

I want to reset the data store clean by removing the app's sqlite file. I wrote this function in my data helper class:

```
-(void) resetPersistenStore {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [persistentStoreCoordinator_ release];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    managedObjectModel_ = nil;
}
```

I put this following test in UIApplication::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    /* test */
    [TestDataHelper populateTestData:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [TestDataHelper populateTestData:[self managedObjectContext]]; 
    [self resetPersistenStore];
    [TestDataHelper populateTestData:[self managedObjectContext]]; 
    [TestDataHelper testPopulateTestData:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

Instead of one set of data created by the function populateTestData, I can see actually three set of data (because I called the function three times)

It is clear that resetPersistenStore() works, because without it, the data will keep accumulating.

So my question is:

**Why the reset does not take effect immediately?**

I have set managedObjectContext to nil in the reset function, but it did not help.

Here is my populateTestData function

```
+(void)populateTestData:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext {

    Stock* s1 = (Stock*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Stock" 
                                                                     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    s1.code = @"ABC2";
    s1.name = @"ABC";
    s1.enteredBy = @"akong";

    [managedObjectContext save:&error]; 

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Data error %@", [error description]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Init completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the context saved the data in `populateTestData`, it still has data loaded in it.

Suppose when the application starts, the file has 3 objects. Now the first `populateTestData` message adds an object into the context, and save it. So 4 objects in the file, 1 in the context. After the second message, 5 in the file, 2 in the context. Now the file is gone, but still there are 2 in the context. Now the final message adds another object to the context and to the file, so there are 3 objects.

You said setting managedObjectContext to nil in the reset function didn't help. I doubt if the context has been properly reset there. Try [managedObjectContext reset] instead.

Comment: I added [managedObjectContext reset] before managedObjectModel_ = nil; but it does not has any effect

Answer (score 0):

I am only speculating here but are you by any chance using a fetchedResultsController to verify/display the results of these operations? If so try to set its caching to nil and see if it helps.

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"xxxxxxxx" cacheName:nil];
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Or, delete the cache:  `[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:]`

Answer (score 0):

It may simply be an artifact of the simulator.  If you're running in the simulator, you may need to reset it.  From the iOS Simulator menu, select Reset Content and Settings...